# Drupal 6 to 7: add jquery function to form

Tags: jquery, forms, function, drupal-7, parameter-passing

I need to convert code from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 but stuck at the part for jquery. In Drupal 6, the code to add jquery is as the following in which `simpleColor` is a function in `jquery.simple-color.min.js`:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/jquery.simple-color.min.js', 'module', 'header', FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);

$jquery = '
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".simple_color").simpleColor({
      displayColorCode: true,
      boxWidth: "6em",
      defaultColor: "#36c",
    });
  });';

drupal_add_js($jquery, 'inline');
```

The simple_color has been added into form:

```
$form['feeds']["feed_$fid"]['color'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Color'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 10,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'simple_color',
  ),
);
```

I has tried to convert the above code to Drupal 7 but unsuccessful:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name').'/js/jquery.simple-color.min.js', array('type'=>'module', 'scope'=>'header', 'defer'=>FALSE, 'cache'=>FALSE, 'preprocess'=>FALSE));

$jquery = '
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".simple_color").simpleColor = {
      attach: function({
        displayColorCode: true,
        boxWidth: "6em",
        defaultColor: "#36c"
    })
  };
});';

drupal_add_js($jquery, array('type'=>'inline'));
```

In form:

```
$form['feeds']["feed_$fid"]['color'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Color'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 10,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('simple_color'),
  ),
);
```

I have try many ways but they didn't work for this case. Please take sometime to have a look and try to help me. Thanks ahead.

Comment: where is your code being added? In a hook? you should use drupal behaviours rather than document.ready. See the documentation at: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7

Comment: @2pha: my drupal_add_js codes have been added to a hook menu's callback function which later on call drupal_get_form in which the form with class 'simple_color' is created. I will look at drupal behaviour and try that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the suggestion from 2pha, I have successfully added jquery code to drupal. The following is the fix in drupal 7:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module-name') . '/js/jquery.simple-color.min.js','file');

$jquery = '
  (function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".simple_color").simpleColor({
          displayColorCode: true,
          boxWidth: "6em",
          defaultColor: "#36c",
        });
      });
    }
  };
  })(jQuery);';
```